# AngularJS: Get $http.post data in JSP

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp

I wrote the below code to send the $http.post request

```
$http({
    url: '/OA_HTML/ReportColumnSelection.jsp',
    method: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({myData : $scope.reportColumns}),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'}
  })
  .success(function(response){
    $scope.viewColumns = response.columnData;
  })
  .error(function(response){
    //Error Log
    console.log('Inside saveReportColumns Error');
  });
```

Now the problem is i'm unable to get the "myData" JSON in ReportColumnSelection.jsp

```
request.getParameter("myData");
```

Please let me know if i'm doing anything wrong.

> AngularJS Version 1.4.7

Code to save report columns:

```
$scope.saveReportColumns = function () { 
        console.log('Inside saveReportColumns'); 
        $http({ url: '/OA_HTML/eis/jsp/reporting/reports/newreport/columnselection/EISRSCReportColumn‌​SelectionAM.jsp', 
        method: 'POST', 
        data: JSON.stringify({myData:$scope.reportColumns}), 
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
        } 
    }).success(function(response){}).error(function(response){ 
        //Error Log console.log('Inside saveReportColumns Error');
    }); 
};
```

Comment: Can you post some more code from your JSP where you post the request and handles the response?

Comment: Di you try `data: {myData : $scope.reportColumns},`?

Comment: @dfsq thanks for the suggestion. The issue got resolved when i sent the request as you suggested and in response i used request.getInputStream()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$http` services default content type is `application/json`, which your JSP cannot parse.

You can either,

- change the content type of the request to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8` (which might have other implications)

or

- read it as a stream like below.

`InputStream body = request.getInputStream();`

It might be a good idea to leave the content type as it is, and instead read the request body and parse it with a library such as [google/json](https://github.com/google/gson)

```
BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
Gson gson = new Gson();
```

Comment: the problem got solved with your solution. I'm able to get the JSON. Issue is i have to use Java 1.4, sadly GSON doesn't support this vesrion :(

Comment: I removed the content type and used [JSON](https://codeload.github.com/chargebee/JSON-java/zip/master) which is compatible with Java 1.4